# How to stop .htaccess instructions without rewrite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am working on a codeigniter project. In my .htaccess file I have:

```
1 RewriteEngine on
2 RewriteRule ^subfolder1/(.*)$ subfolder1/$1 [L] # pass through for subfolder1

.... additional instructions
```

I have been getting a 500 Internal Server Error

According to my ISP ( this is in a shared environment so I can't see the logs ), the second line above is causing a rewrite loop, resulting in the error. Is there a way to stop executions of instructions at line 2 without rewiting and causing the loop if subfolder1 is in the request? in pseudocode:

```
if ^subfolder1/(.*)$ STOP HERE ([L])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rule should end the rewriting process in the way you want:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder1/ - [L]
```

Using just a `-` as the substitution instructs the RewriteEngine to just leave the URL alone, but still apply the `L` (stop) flag.

Answer (score 1):

another approach would be to put another .htaccess file inside subfolder1 with

```
RewriteEngine off
```